# How to avoid alert displayed multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

The webpage has an UpdatePanel with a grid view having checkboxes on each row, and a couple of buttons of the same class "cssUpdateEM". Outside the update panel I have another button "btnExportToExcel" having the "cssUpdateEM" class.

The buttons within the update panel, if clicked, display the alert message (if no items selected) only once. The issue is with the outer button "btnExportToExcel". If the page is posted back n times, and btnExportToExcel is clicked, and no items selected, the alert message will show n times instead of only once.

```js
//**************************
// Pick the selected Items
//**************************
                $('.cssUpdateEM').click(function () {
                    var SelectedEMItemIDs = "";
                    var strDelim = "";
                    $('.cssItemEM').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).is(':checked') == true) {
                            SelectedEMItemIDs += strDelim + $(this).attr('eid');
                            strDelim = ";";
                        }
                    });
                    if (SelectedEMItemIDs == "") {
                        alert('Please select the item(s).');
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#hdnSelectedItemID').attr('Value', SelectedEMItemIDs);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any idea why is this happening, and how to fix this?

Comment: create var counter = 0 in a global scope so if(counter == 0)alert("your string here")

Comment: Is the `click` event handler applied to the class every time "the page is posted back"? Then the function will run multiple times. If that is the problem, it could be solved using the jQuery plugin [Once](http://plugins.jquery.com/once/).

Comment: The problem with the once/one approach is that the event handler function needs to be executed every time the button is clicked, but the alert should not be displayed n consecutive times per one button click (as is the case of the n-th postback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I'd like to mention that I'm using a master page.

So, *code before*:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function BindControlEvents() {
    //jQuery is wrapped in BindControlEvents function so it can be re-bound after each callback.

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.cssUpdateEM').click(function () {
                //the original function body here
            });

           // ... other functions here

        })
    }

// ... other functions here
```

The script ends with:

```
    Sys.Application.add_load(BindControlEvents);
</script>
```

The *code after* has the btnExportToExcel event handler moved outside of the $(document).ready.

```
$('#btnExportToExcel').click(function () {
    //code including the alert here
}
```

I hope this explanation will help somebody, sometime.